# How to read a text file using pl/sql and do string search for each line

Tags: sql, string, oracle, file, plsql

I want to read text file and store(using clob datatype) its data in table . I want to do string comparison on loaded data.

Loaded text file contains DDL scripts and i want to get segregation of new/modified tables, new/modified indexes and constraints.

This can be done as Tom suggested [Ask tom article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:475021425271)

Challenge i'm facing here is that, i have to get above details before running those scripts, otherwise i would have used some DDL trigger to audit schema changes.

My qustion is , is it feasible to do string comparison on large text ? or is there any better alternative. please share your views/ideas on this.

Example file

```
Create table table_one

Alter table table_two

create index index_table_one_idx table_one (column_one)

etc etc... 100s of statements
```

from above code i want to get **table_one , table_two** as modified tables, and *index_table_one_idx* as newly created index.

i want to achieve this by looking for 'create table','alter table' strings in large text file and get the table name using substring.

Comment: That's plenty of work to be done. You could split your assignment in a set of simple tasks (read text file, store text in CLOB, etc.), then do your work, and come back with a specific problem once your really stuck. Here it looks like you ask us to do your job.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: i think you didn't understand the question.. i have put my analysis here and asked question later.. to avoid multiple clarifications from user who is willing to answer.   If you don't know the answer just move on.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly feasible to do string comparison on large text.

There are a couple of different approaches. One is to read the file line by line using [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF). The other word be to load it into a temporary CLOB and process it in chunks. Probably the second way is is the better option. Make sure to use the DBMS_LOB functions for string manipulation, because they will perform better. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600).

Your main problem is a specification one. You need to isolate all the different starting points for SQL statements. If your script just as CREATE, ALTER and DROP then it's not too difficult, depending on how much subsequent detail you need (extract object type? extract object name? etc) and what additional processing you need to do.

If your scripts contain DML statements the task becomes harder. If the DDL encompasses programmatic objects (TYPE, PACKAGE, etc) then it's an order of magnitude harder.

Comment: Thanks... my scripts contains only DML that to modifies/creates tables , constraints , indexes .. if table is modified subsequently i want to get modified column names , index, constraints..